# How do I tell webdriver to skip urls in a list if they return connection refused?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a python script that loops through urls (ip addresses) for IoT devices to gather info from them. Every now and then I have one or two that say connection refused and the site wont load. It does this with and without selenium. How can I tell my script to skip over a non working url and go to the next url in the list and loop through the actions again? Currently it hits the non working URL and the script stops all together.

Here is the error I am getting:

> Exception has occurred: WebDriverException

> Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

You can use try/except block and check if the error says

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

You need to import WebDriverException to be able to catch the error
This code will look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
urls = ['http://localhost', 'http://localhost:9000', 'https://seleniumbase.io/demo_page/']
for url in urls:
    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except WebDriverException as err:
        if 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' in err.msg:
            pass
        else:
            raise err
    print(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h1').text)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I put try: driver.get(URL), then except: continue and for else, i ran the rest of the actions it normally would. Would it benefit me to specify the WebDriverException as the error?

Comment: What do you mean? Specify `WebDriverException as error` instead of `WebDriverException as err`?